# Quotients of Measurable Spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $\Pi$ be a partition of $\Omega$. There is a projection $\pi:\Omega\to\Pi$ that maps each $\omega\in\Omega$ to the unique partition cell in $\Pi$ containing $\omega$. We can endow $\Pi$ with the largest $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_\Pi$ that makes $\pi$ measurable. It is easily shown that $\Sigma_\Pi=\{A\subseteq\Pi:\cup A\in\Sigma\}$.

This seems to be the most natural way to construct a quotient of a measurable space. I'm sure someone must have used this construction before, but I couldn't find a single paper making use of it. In general, outside of statistical decision theory and topological measure theory, there seems to be little work on measurable spaces in themselves. To focus:

> Are there any papers or texts that
>   study this quotient construction and
>   its properties? Are there other
>   commonly used quotient constructions
>   for measurable spaces?

Edit: Additional question:

> What are sufficient conditons for $\Sigma_\Pi$ to be countably generated?

The problem here is that generators for $\Sigma$ cannot simply be transferred to generators of $\Sigma_\Pi$.

Comment: Rokhlin's book "On the fundamental ideas of measure theory" develops a theory of measurable partitions...

Comment: Sometimes they just look at one of these as a counterexample.  The quotient sigma-algebra for $\mathbb R / \mathbb Q$ .  Or the "tail" sigma-algebra in a product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ where the factors $T_n$ are nice.  Or the "countable subsets of $\mathbb R$ ", realized as the sequences $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ modulo the permutations. A point is: if it is not countably separated, then such a sigma-algebra is **very bad** in a sense that logicians will tell you about.

Comment: Rohlin's book is very intersting. It can be found at: http://ma.huji.ac.il/~matang02/rohlin.pdf

Comment: In the special case that $\Sigma$ is standard Borel (generated by a Polish topology), this sort of question has been extensively studied among descriptive set theorists.  For example, if $\Pi$ is a partition arising from a Borel equivalence relation, the quotient $\sigma$-algebra is countably generated if and only if there is a Borel assignment of real invariants to the equivalence classes.  In the special case that the equivalence relation has countable classes (among other such special cases), this is equivalent to finding a Borel set which intersects each class in exactly one point.  Etc.

Comment: Note that if your original $\Sigma$ is countably generated and separates points, it is automatically standard Borel, so the previous comment applies.

Comment: Thank you! Could you recommend a reference (as a starting point) for these kinds of results?

Comment: A countable generated $\sigma$-algebra that separates points is not necessarily standard Borel. If the continuum hypothesis is wrong, we can take the trace $\sigma$-algebra  of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of an uncountable set of real numbers with cardinality less than $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: A good default reference for properties of standard Borel spaces would be Kechris' descriptive set theory text.  More recent references about equivalence relations in particular include Kanovei's _Borel Equivalence Relations_ and Gao's _Invariant Descriptive Set Theory_.  Also noteworthy is the Jackson, Kechris, Louveau paper entitled "Countable Borel equivalence relations," J. Math. Logic.

Comment: You are right; I meant to say "restriction of a standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra."  I'm not having good luck posting coherently lately.

Comment: I think [this question of mine](http://mathoverflow.net/q/176459/11768) is related, though I am not sure whether the maximal/minimal $\sigma$-algebra would work there.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker The link for the Rohlin book isn't working. What was the book?

Comment: @AidanYoung "On the fundamental ideas of measure theory". It's more of a booklet though; 54 pages in total.